# add attachment as stream in commons email

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, apache-commons-email

I am using [Apache Commons Email](http://commons.apache.org/email/) in my web-application and it works fine.

Now that I need to send a document by attachment, I am facing some problems. I need to get the file from the database (as a BLOB) and add it as an attachment. It seems like Commons Email does not support stream attachment and it only takes a file from a path.

I need to know what is the best practice here?

1. Do I need to save the file in the directory structure also, so that
   it works fine with Commons Email?, or,
2. Is there any way I can use the
   streamed content itself to add as an attachment?

Answer (score 23):

Using [MultiPartEmail#attach(DataSource ds, String name, String description)](http://commons.apache.org/email/apidocs/org/apache/commons/mail/MultiPartEmail.html#attach%28javax.activation.DataSource,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) should work:

```
import org.apache.commons.mail.*;

// create the mail
MultiPartEmail email = new MultiPartEmail();
email.setHostName("mail.myserver.com");
email.addTo("jdoe@somewhere.org", "John Doe");
email.setFrom("me@apache.org", "Me");
email.setSubject("The picture");
email.setMsg("Here is the picture you wanted");

// get your inputstream from your db
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(MyUtils.getBlob());  
DataSource source = new ByteArrayDataSource(is, "application/pdf");  

// add the attachment
email.attach(source, "somefile.pdf", "Description of some file");

// send the email
email.send();
```

Comment: Thanks, worked fine. Although I have no idea what the file description is for. I didn't see anywhere in the received email.